# iOS 10.2 Cordova file plugin trying to load local images into DOM

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, dom, content-security-policy

This was working on iOS 10.02 but after the upgrade, I can't load `cdvfile://` urls or `file://` into the DOM.

I get this error when using `file://`:

```
Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)
```

And I get this error when trying to load `cdvfile://`:

```
Failed to load resource: unsupported URL
```

I've tried 50 or so content security policies so I don't think that's the problem.

Here's the kicker. This works on iOS 10.2 via simulator. But not on the actual device.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I believe you are using WKWebview, right? If you use UIWebView, it should work fine..

Comment: Hi, i know this is quite old, but we got the same exact error when we started using cordova 5.1.1 with wkWebView. We load images from "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{...}/Library/files/some/path/to/file" but we get kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1. Did you happen to find a solution?